# Executing MySQL SELECT * query in parallel

Tags: mysql, multithreading, mysql-python

I have a multithreaded application that periodically fetches the whole content of the MySQL table (with SELECT * FROM  query)
The application is written in python, uses threading module to multithreading and uses mysql-python (mysqldb) as MySQL driver (using mysqlalchemy as a wrapper produces similar results).
I use InnoDB engine for my MySQL database.

I wrote a simple test to check the performance of SELECT * query in parallel and discovered that all of those queries are implemented sequentially.

I explicitly set the ISOLATION LEVEL to READ UNCOMMITTED, although it does not seem to help with performance.

The code snipper making the DB call is below:

```
@performance.profile()
def test_select_all_raw_sql(conn_pool, queue):
    ''' 
    conn_pool - connection pool to get mysql connection from
    queue - task queue
    '''
    query = '''SELECT * FROM table'''
    try:
        conn = conn_pool.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED")
        # execute until the queue is empty (Queue.Empty is thrown)
        while True:
            id = queue.get_nowait()
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
    except Queue.Empty:
            pass
    finally:
        cursor.execute("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ")
        conn.close()
```

Am I right expecting this query to be executed in parallel?
If yes, how can I implement that in python?

Comment: I don't fully understand why you care how the database executes the query.  The results have to be serialized to be returned to the application.

Comment: Well I care because if database locks the whole table for the execution, it affects all other queries executing in parallel and therefore affects the performance of the service using the database

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows many *connections* from a single *user* or many *users*.  Within that one connection, it uses at most one CPU core and does one SQL statement at a time.

A "transaction" can be composed of multiple SQL statements while the transaction is *treated* as atomically.  Consider the classic banking application:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...  -- decrement from one user's bank balance.
UPDATE ...  -- increment another user's balance.
COMMIT;
```

Those statements are performed serially (in a single connection); either all of them succeed or all of them fail as a unit ("atomically").

If you need to do things in "parallel", have a client (or clients) that can run multiple threads (or processes) and have each on make its own connection to MySQL.

A minor exception:  There are some extra threads 'under the covers' for doing background tasks such as read-ahead or delayed-write or flushing stuff.  But this does *not* give the user a way to "do two things at once" in a single connection.

What I have said here applies to all versions of MySQL/MariaDB and all client packages accessing them.