# MySQL select request in parallel (python)

Tags: python, mysql, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I saw a "similar" post [Executing MySQL SELECT * query in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619856/executing-mysql-select-query-in-parallel), buy my question is different, and this has not been answered either, so i guess its not a duplicate.

I am trying to do a MySQL select request in parallel. The reason is because i need the response fast. I managed to create the request when i paralleled the connection as well, but as the connection takes more time then the actual `select` it would be faster to connect one time, and do the `select` in parallel.

My approach:

```
import mysql.connector
import multiprocessing

def func(id):
    return GetFasta(id, cnx).sequence()

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='U_NAME', host='IP_ADDR', database='DB_NAME')
p = multiprocessing.Pool()

for x in p.imap_unordered(func, ["Q32P44", "ASD"]):
    print x

p.close()
p.join()
cnx.close()
```

The `GetFasta` is a `Class` and its working as intended, requires a connector, and an ID and does a simple `SELECT` with those.

If i execute this script the interpreter freezes, and i have to kill it manually. I guess it is either not this trivial, or maybe impossible to `select` in parallel with one connector.

Is it?

Any workaround?

Comment: If you are using `multiprocessing`, I'd suggest not using it in the interpreter.  It could work when you are running as a script, however.  It also has a chance of working if you define `func` in another file that you will then import.  Alternately, try using `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing`, as the `multiprocess` fork provides better serialization, which is the usual culprit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the "solution" after a lot of research. It is actually not possible. MySQL does not support parallel queries from the same <strike>user</strike> *connection*. It is absolutely impossible, and there are no plans to add this.

The best you can get is the way i implemented it, so parallel the connection as well.

In some other types of databases it is possible, but for now i ll stick with MySQL and use the parallel connection method